# com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: A request was unmatched by any stub mapping

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to create simple wiremock test app. I created stubs in mapping.json file but while running the test using "mvn clean test", I am getting VerificationException. My java code is-

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/resources/";
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    verify(getRequestedFor(urlPathEqualTo("/api/resources/"))
            .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json")));
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing. Json file-

```
        {
        "mappings": [
            {
                "request": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "url": "/api/resources"
                },
                "response": {
                    "status": 200,
                    "bodyFileName": "Wiremock-test.json",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
        }
```

---

Comment: Does your WireMock server start up correctly? AFAIK, you can't start a server with the mapping json having a `mappings` array, that feature can only be used if you add the mapping via the admin call to update mappings.

Comment: If I keep it direct in src folder then it works fine. If I put it mappings inside any folder then it fails.

Comment: I don't think I understand - what are the file paths where it works/doesn't work? And if you start the server and just hit the server, do you get the expected response (not in the verification test)?